# facebook sdk question regarding dialog feed iphone

Tags: ios4, facebook

I use this code to post in facebook from my app in iphone

```
   NSString *title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted from Poems of Love v2 iPhone/iPod/iPad touch app - { Poem Name: "]; 
//& titletext.text & ""\",";
 NSString *alltitle= [title stringByAppendingString:poemtitle.text]; 
alltitle= [alltitle stringByAppendingString:@" } - { Author:"];
alltitle= [alltitle stringByAppendingString:authorname.text]; 
NSString *alltitle1= [alltitle stringByAppendingString:@" }"]; 

    NSString *list = poembody.text;
    NSString *kAppId=@"numid";
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   @"http://www.poemsofloveapp.com", @"link",
                                   @"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_co4MVQE_2l0/TPRh6TBjaZI/AAAAAAAAAOg/E0kgWLd4ieE/s1600/poemsoflovev2logo.png", @"picture",
                                   alltitle1, @"name",
                                   @"\nhttp://www.poemsofloveapp.com - Join us on facebook!\n", @"caption",
                                   list, @"description",
                                   @"",@"message",
                                   nil];
    [mainDelegate._session dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

The dialog shows up i tap skip or publish and then a second dialog shows up which is empty! no message on it nothing

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake sorry guys i called [mainDelegate._session dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
two times previously stupid i know!!!